# If $1<a<b$, when is $a^b>b^a$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given $a,b\in \mathbb{N}$ where $1<a<b$, when is it so that $a^b > b^a$?

I feel like this should be a known result but I cannot for the life of me find it.

Comment: Huh?  $a=2, b=3$?

Comment: Perhaps you need that $a\ge 3$ or $b\ge 5$. Note that $2^4=4^2$.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense :-)

Comment: Edited for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

Over $\Bbb R$, with $1<a<b$, $a^b>b^a$ is equivalent to $b\ln a>a\ln b$, or
to $(\ln a)/a>(\ln b)/b$. The function $f(x)=(\ln x)/x$ has a maximum at $e$.
Thus if $e<a<b$, then certainly $a^b>b^a$. But if $1<a<e<b$, then all bets are off...